# Reduce overlapping of JWebBrowser in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am developing application based on Swing.

My problem is I use [JWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/components/JWebBrowser.html) and I put one in a scrollable panel.  When I scroll down the panel the web browser overlaps the panel/frame of the application.

What can I do so the browser does not overlap the panel?

Comment: I added a link to the docs. for a `JWebBrowser`.  Please check it is the right one.

Comment: HI please give me the code snippet what to do? As I new to java swing, i do not have any idea about the docs for JWebBrowser. please give me reply as fast as possible. thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd never heard of it before your question.  As to the problem, the only thing I can think of is that either a) it is very poorly written, or b) you are trying to put it into a GUI that also has AWT components.  BTW *"please give me the code snippet what to do?"* translates to *"please do it for me"* in my head, and that rarely goes well for the asker.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for "please do it for me".And you are right that I am trying to put it into a GUI that also has AWT components.But I have requirement for that,So i use that way.But now what can i do?

Comment: *"But I have requirement for that,.."*  What AWT components, and why use AWT over the Swing equivalents?  As a general bit of advice, when you have a strange requirement (e.g. mixing GUI components between a modern API and another over 10 years old), add the ***why?***

Comment: I change to swing components, but still it create the same problem.

Comment: OK time to look at an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which replicates the problem.  Admittedly it won't truly be an SSCCE with a 3rd party API, but maybe I can spot a problem in the J2SE code.  Make sure it is the version that is 'all Swing' and like advised in the SSCCE document, strip it back to the minimum needed to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an answer here, so as someone who has been down this bumpy road, I can sympathize with these issues and would like provide some guidance.

First of all, the `JWebBrowser` is an AWT heavyweight component, and does not play nicely in Swing (since it uses lightweight components) without some intervention.

Instantiate `JWebBrowser` like this for the first step of friendly Swing integration:

```
new JWebBrowser(NSComponentOptions.destroyOnFinalization(),
                NSComponentOptions.constrainVisibility(),
                NSComponentOptions.proxyComponentHierarchy())
```

That instantiation alone should prevent the browser from overlapping the Swing lightweight components, however, it will not work as you would expect with transparencies or layers unless you do some additional steps.

So, during construction, call these:

```
webBrowser.setDoubleBuffered(true);
webBrowser.getNativeComponent().createBackBuffer();
```

And then, right before the web browser is to be used with any kind of transparency or layers, call these:

```
rects[0] = webBrowser.getBounds();
webBrowser.getNativeComponent().updateBackBuffer(rects);
```

Those calls will repaint the backbuffer right before the component is to be used and so when being used, it will be displayed with that most recent backbuffer and will look pretty much like a regular Swing component at that point.

There are some nuances with all of this, but that's the basics and should be enough to get anyone started with it.